# Can you create a directory and add a file to it with one command in the Terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal

I'm just learning the command line and trying figure out if I can write multiple actions with one line in Terminal.

For example, if I wanted to to create a new folder (mkdir) called "website", and then add two files (index.html and style.css) to it, can I do that with one line of code, or do I need to do it separately? What's the shortest way to write it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `&&` command in the terminal.

```
$ command1 && command2 && ...
```

It will not run command2 until command1 finished successfully.

So in this case, maybe you can try:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/my_dir && touch /tmp/my_dir/my_file
```

If you want to learn more about how to Chain Linux Commands together.

[Check out this post](http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/07/23-awesome-less-known-linuxunix-command-chaining-examples.html)

Comment: awesome. that's exactly what I was looking for. As a follow-up question, can you do infinite additions using &&?

Comment: You can also chain together with semicolon, e.g.: ls -l;cd dir;ls -l;cd /

Comment: @BryceJohnson Glad my answer helped, there are a lot of interesting tricks in shell, I just update my post with a link to the topic `Chain Commands` and hope you will like it. (BTW, I have no problem chaining 4 commands in one line and I can't see why it will not do more.